# api test authorization token in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

## I have to pass an existing token which returns

me a 201. But it only returns 400

class NotifyViewTests(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
self.user = User.objects.create_user(
name='test',
email='tes111t@test.com',
password='test123',
)
#self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
self.user.save()
headers = "Token 9549dee7-6d98-499c-8d33-6ecfc4a9c6e0"
self.headers = f'{headers}'
print(self.headers)

```
def test_notify_api_success(self):                   
    url = reverse('notify')           
    data = {
        "template_code": "interaction",
        "from_type": "user",
        "from_uuid": "5aef85d2-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
        "to_type": "user",
        "to_uuid": "6920f096-1445-11ee-be56-0242ac120002",
        "params": {
            "problem_title": "Titulo teste de um problema",
            "problem_desc": "Descrição teste de um problema"
        }                                  
    }     
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user,
                                    token=self.headers)
    response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')                                    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,
                      status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```